# Load and Performance testing on android and ios app

Tags: performance-testing, load-testing

I need to perform a load test with **200+** concurrent devices on the android and ios apps. Is there any tool that can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the [network protocol(s)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_network_protocols) which your application is using for communicating with the backend.

You can identify which protocol(s) are in scope by installing the application into [Android Emulator](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator) or [iOS Simulator](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/iOS_Simulator_Guide/GettingStartedwithiOSSimulator/GettingStartedwithiOSSimulator.html) and use a sniffer tool like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) to capture the network traffic.

Once you figure out which protocol(s) are being used you can choose a proper load testing tool which supports this(ese) protocol(s), an example comparison of free and open source load testing tools can be found i.e. in [Open Source Load Testing Tools: Which One Should You Use?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/open-source-load-testing-tools-which-one-should-you-use/) article

After you decide which tool you will be using you will need to replicate mobile device traffic using the tool of your choice to 100% match the network footprint of the mobile device (you might need to perform parameterization of credentials and correlation of dynamic parameters) and as soon as it will be done you should be able to replay the requests with increased number of virtual users.

Answer (score 0):

Try [AWS Device Farm](https://aws.amazon.com/es/device-farm/) they have a lot of configurations, devices and global options for testing.

Answer (score 0):

Typically

1. you capture the device network requests using a proxy (we use charles proxy) as you are functional testing the app
2. Take out static resources, css, images, scripts (which are served from a cdn) and third party resources
3. then parameterise the dynamic requests to create a load test script

While you are perf testing, monitor navigate through the app to see the end-user impact when the back-end is under heavy load.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are many solutions.  The governing factor is going to be the communications model between your handheld device and the application/system under test.

In most cases (but not all) the protocol for communication is HTTP.  In this case you may leverage a proxy for recording the conversation between client and server to reproduce the conversation of a single session. You may then modify this session to address dynamic server data for session, date, time, account information and user inputs.  Once that is done then you may replay 200++ session representing the load of 200++ users on your system.

I would recommend a network simulator be involved in your test.  Mobile networks are particularly dirty, leading to higher error rates and longer latch times (protocol, layer 3) on sites.  Having the impairment from the network simulator will better allow you to understand the response times for your client.  Look for impairment solutions which can ingest OOKLA data for various locations and times of day matching your high load windows.